# How to use SageMaker, BlazingText, and Labeling Jobs

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I have done some searching on how to use the UI console for creating a ground truth labeling job to creating a model from this labeling job and not getting the outputs I expect.

The first question is, I have labeled probably a hundred parts of a text in the ground truth job and submitted the labels. But when I look at the labeled objects/total, it shows 0.

Then, after creating a training job from the ground truth labeling job's output, creating a model package from the training job, and finally creating a batch transform job from that model package, the output from the batch transform job is not what is expected.

The expected output should be a json object containing the the text with the label, but the output I'm getting is below.

What do I need to do to get the expected results?

[{"vector": http://0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, "word": "t-6 - hard leather tobacco r11 24\" x 48\" = 744 sf"}, {"vector": http://0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, "word": "t-6 - hard leather tobacco r11 24\" x 48\" = 264 sf"}, {"vector":...

Answer (score 0):

I'm an engineer on the SageMaker service team. As a starting point, I would encourage you to look through this sample notebook (if you haven't already) that demonstrates how to train BlazingText for text classification purposes (https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/introduction_to_amazon_algorithms/blazingtext_text_classification_dbpedia/blazingtext_text_classification_dbpedia.ipynb). There are a few nuances here, e.g., be sure that the "mode" parameter is set to "supervised". Please note that this example will not exactly mirror your use case - I understand you're trying to use the SageMaker augmented manifest format for training, whereas this example uses a different input format - but it's still an illustrative resource.

In order to help answer your questions more deeply, I'd like to see more information on the specific resources involved here. For privacy/security reasons, I don't want to ask you to expose those in this SO thread. Would you please submit a support ticket through your AWS account? Don't worry about exactly where it gets sent - if you can provide the ticket number, I'll make sure it gets routed back to us.